# Unknown attributeDescription inserted

Tags: ldap, openldap

After modifying schema on my test OpenLDAP server I started getting messages like this when I issue slapschema command or when I convert my slapd.conf to slapd.d (/usr/sbin/slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d/):

```
5a8e025e UNKNOWN attributeDescription "X-ATTRIBUTE" inserted.
```

During my schema modification I first removed that attribute from all entries that had it and after that from the schema file (and restarted server).

There was no attribute "x-attribute" showing anywhere in slapcat output but that message was still showing up. At the end only when I deleted database (data.mdb) and recreated it message was gone.

How can I properly remove attribute from LDAP server (including from schema file also) and avoid messages like that?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you missed some entry, and now you cannot see it because the attribute is unknown. Try defining the attribute again, then double check it was really removed from all entries.